add username in a massage box in excel (vba)
I am currently using a text box, to start a process in excel VBA with the following vba script:
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

Dim lResult As Long

'Message Box
If MsgBox("START?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Achtung") = vbYes Then


lResult = Application.Run("SAPExecutePlanningSequence", "PS_4")
lResult = Application.Run("SAPExecuteCommand", "PlanDataSave")

End If

End Sub

How Can I add the current excel username that the output will be with the username before start?

I tried:
If MsgBox(Application.UserName, "START?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Achtung") = vbYes Then

but that leads to an error.

Google VBA string concatenation. MsgBox(Application.UserName & ", START?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Achtung") You get an error because you can't just start adding new parameters to a function or sub - if it requires three arguments, you can't pass it four just because you feel like it. (And FYI: leads to an error is not a problem description unless you tell us the specific error that you're seeing, including the complete, exact error message.)
